# Pyqt5: QtableWidgetItem "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have created a table in PyQt5 and and retrieve the data in the cell by this method. But when i try the cell in QTableWidgetItem becomes None. So, how i can solve this problem and how i can insert other determined items in a specifice cell for exemple item 2, item3,... Thank you

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor 
from PyQt5 import QtCore

data = {'111':['Title 1','121','94565','','','','684651','','','44651','','',''], '112':['Title 2','65115','','466149','46645','555641','','','','412045','98416','',''], '113':['Title 3','','','','466149','46645','555641','98656','','','412045','98416','','']} 

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.setuptUI()
        k = 'str'
        v = int
        n = int
        m = int
        self.setdata(k, v, n, m)

def setuptUI(self):
  self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidgetItem")
                self.resize(1200, 800)
                conLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.tableWidget =QTableWidget(self)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(55)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(14)
    conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

def setdata(self, k, v, n, m):
    global item
    item = str(self.data.get(k))
    for key in self.data:
        if k in key:
            item = self.data.get(k)[v]
            print(item)
    newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
    newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(23, 4, newItem)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windows = Table(data)
    item1= Table()
    item1.setdata(k="113", v=5, n=24, m=4)
    #item2= Table()
    #item2.setdata(k="113", v=5, n=25, m=4
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTableWidget, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor 
from PyQt5 import QtCore

data = {'111':['Title 1','121','94565','','','','684651','','','44651','','',''], 
        '112':['Title 2','65115','','466149','46645','555641','','','','412045','98416','',''], 
        '113':['Title 3','','','','466149','46645','555641','98656','','','412045','98416','','']} 

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):                              # data
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.setuptUI()

#        k = 'str'
#        v = int
#        n = int
#        m = int
#        self.setdata(k, v, n, m)

    def setuptUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidgetItem")
        self.resize(1200, 600)

        conLayout        = QHBoxLayout(self)                 # + self
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(55)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(14)
        conLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def setdata(self, k, v, n, m):
#        global item                                          # ---
#        item = str(self.data.get(k))
#        for key in self.data:
#            if k in key:
        item = self.data.get(k)[v]
        print(item)

        newItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
        newItem.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0)))
#        self.tableWidget.setItem(23, 4, newItem)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(n, m, newItem)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    windows = Table(data)
#-    item1= Table()
#-    item1.setdata(k="113", v=5, n=24, m=4)
    windows.setdata(k="113", v=5, n=24, m=4)
    windows.setdata(k="113", v=6, n=24, m=5)         #  v=6, m=5

    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: but in other modul it show me Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You apparently set the key (k = "555") which is not in the dictionary

Comment: Insert a line `print("Value : %s" %  data.get(k, "Never"))` before the line `item = self.data.get(k)[v]` and see what will be printed.

Comment: it show me Value : Never
And if i remove [v] the error is:
TypeError: updateData() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'v', 'n', and 'm'

Comment: I figured out the problem bro, in this module i've a method 1 that transforme a CSV file to a dictionary. In the first state the dictionary was empty and when I called the method 1 the dictionary becomes full. Meanwhile the method 2 "setdata" reference to the state of empty dictionary and not the full one, that's why it shows me None, even if I printed the dictionary will shows me {}. So if you have an idea how to use the dictionary from the method 1?